# Delphi mobile app - store data across new mobile phones

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe7

Is there any standardized way in Delphi mobile apps for storing/syncing app data across mobile phones for Android + iOS?

Here is my siuation:

Currently I ship some data with my apps and new data is downloaded to cache. This works well, also when users download new versions.

However, now I need to store data inputted by the user... Thus data needs to be persistent... And ideally it should survive mobile changes, e.g. from ios to android or at east when upgrading from e.g. iphone5 to iphone6. I rather **not** host user data myself on my own servers. It it also important that it is cost free.

So I am looking at what is necessary for:

1. App/user data survives upgrading Android phone keeping Google Play account.
2. App/user data survives upgrading iphone keeping Apple iTunes account.
3. App/user data when user changes mobile platform.

I guess a combination of these solutions will be necessary:

1. Using a cloud service tied to each separate plaform (i.e. iCloud for iPhone users)
2. Make an import/export function to a data folder the user manually can backup when switching from e.g. Android o iPhone or the other way

The minimal but fully acceptable solution would be an easy way to export/import a data file. That data file could then e.g. be stored in *any* service where it could be retrievd from later?

The amount of data will not be a whole lot. Each user has his/hers own data. If the user uses multiple devices it will be up to the user to export/import/sync data in a way that makes senses.

Comment: "Not on my own servers" and "cost free" are not friends with each other. In fact, they're sworn enemies. If you want your clients to store data in the cloud, you will either need to use your own servers, or pay for a third-party cloud service.

Comment: You can't rely on services such as iCloud, Dropbox, etc. because what if the user doesn't have it enabled? What if they prefer to disable it on their phone (like me)?

Comment: @JerryDodge In this specific cause, requiring e.g. dropbox (or iCloud for OSX) will be okay. As long as it is a major/well-known service that has an API that will work with Delphi.

Comment: One thing you don't address in your question is how much data you'll be saving, how often it needs to be saved, and how many clients do you intend to use it?

Comment: Each user of the app (maybe up to 500) will have own data of maybe 10-100k, i.e. 1/10 megabyte. (With time maybe more.)

Comment: So are you talking about a backup? Or a live connection of multiple devices to the same set of data? Or data specific to a user? Multi-device data should be assumed to be shared across multiple devices via a cloud server. What if that user installs your app on two devices of their own? Do you want both to share the same data? Or do you just want each app install to save into the cloud?

Comment: You could say backup. I just need the data to survive when the user updates his/hers phone and offer a way to transfer the data. Only one user/per dataset. I assume one "active" device at a time for my app, but if not, responsiblity will be on the user to sync/transfer data in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for finally clarifying. Please edit your question to make this clear for other readers :-)

Comment: I have extended it now. Hopefully soeone has an idea - if nothing else, then some kind of import/export solution will suffice.